# (Dygraphs JS) How can I clear (remove) graphics rendered using underlayCallback?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

This should be simple but I have been unable to find a way to do this in the Dygraphs documentation.

If I have generated some custom graphics using `underlayCallback`, then how can I later clear these graphics?

For example, in the highlighted region demo (http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-region), how could I implement a button that *removes* the yellow highlighted region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/cephei/husevsfm/

the important thing is the property `DygraphObject.updateOptions(object)`, with this you can set option underlayCallback to null and you will get the base result

```
$("#mybutton1").click(function () {
    g.updateOptions({
        underlayCallback: null
    });
});
```